# Не подключается к базе данных

Tags: c#, sql

Добрый день, создал я приложение десктопное на C# с помощью Visual Studio, там же создал базу данных, прописал connectionString до базы, все работает в студии, добавляется, удаляется и т.д.

Попробовал поставить виртуалку Windows 7 x64, туда перенёс приложение, захожу в bin/Debug/Myproject.exe запускаю, всё работает. Но когда жму кнопку показать таблицы, то выводит ошибку:

```
provider: sql network interfaces, error: 26 - error locating server/instance specified
```

Хотя в файле App.config я поменял connectionString

Answer (score 1):

1. Убедитесь, что имя сервера указано правильно.
2. В строке коннекта попробуйте оба варианта: Server\Instance и Server\\Instance.
3. Убедитесь, что сервер и DNS доступен (пропингуйте).
4. Убедитесь, что служба SQL Server Browser запущена на сервере.
5. Если на сервере запущен фаервол, убедитесь, что sqlbrowser.exe и UDP порт 1434 добавлены в исключения.

Comment: Думаю, что у вас проблема с 4-м пунктом.